# Is there a Python random.random() analog that does not generate 0

Tags: python, random, divide-by-zero

I'm writing some functions that require division by a random float, and while it's **highly** improbable that it will throw a ZeroDivisionError, I can't sleep until I'm **positive** it won't. Is there a random.random() analog for Python that's 0 exclusive.

Comment: please post your code

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.random it will.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the `random.random` returns values [0.0, 1.0) as pointed out by Kevin Christopher Henry, it is easy to transfrom that into (0.0, 1.0] without any conditional code by:

```
1.0 - random.random()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind writing your own function, here's a go:

```
def rand():
    x = 0
    while x == 0:
            x = random.random()
    return x
```

This keeps picking a random float **until** that random float is not equal to 0, upon which it is returned:

```
>>> def rand():
...     x = 0
...     while x == 0:
...             x = random.random()
...     return x
... 
>>> rand()
0.8330963681114979
>>> rand()
0.6061231841612397
>>> rand()
0.10548161965303249
>>> rand()
0.6102130916030852
```

Comment: "..until that random float is not equal to 0", which is not really any significant overhead. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to transform it from [0.0, 1.0) to (0.0, 1.0]:

```
def nonzero_random():
    return random.random() or 1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

So, if we have a function that takes a range of `[x, y)`, but we want it to take a range of `(x, y)`, then the C++ function [`std::nextafter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter) would solve this problem.

Sadly, a similar function isn't offered in stock python. We can find it in numpy though.

```
random.uniform(numpy.nextafter(0, 1), 1)
```

You could also hardcode the number if you didn't want a dependency on numpy:

```
random.uniform(5e-324, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
random.randrange(start, stop, step)
```

even if you are forced to have a range of integers, you can always divide the results.

```
>>> random.randrange(1, 1000)/ float(1000)
0.428
```